# Dynamically Set object properties to custom objects

Tags: dynamic-apex

I need to dynamically set some values to create/update records of a custom object.

The main idea is to create something like this:

```
MyCustomObject.fields["fieldName"].Value = "some value";
```

Does Apex have any way to do that?

Comment: Is it a custom `SObject` or an instance of a custom `Apex Class`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object is an ambiguous term in this context. If by custom object you mean `SObject`, then it is straightforward as you can use the `put` method inherited from the [`SObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) class:

```
MyCustomObject__c record = new MyCustomObject__c();
record.put('MyCustomField__c', 'Some Value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the put method of the sObject class. This could look like this: `customObj.put('fieldname', field value)`